# How can I get the last uploaded data to Firebase?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('users')
            .where('bmi')
            .limit(1)
            .snapshots(),
        },
      )),


class User {
  final double bmi;

  User(
      {required this.bmi});

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'bmi': bmi,
      };

  static User fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => User(
      bmi: json['bmi']);
}
```

I want to pull the last added 'bmi' value to firebase. Do I need to use the OrderBy() method?

I tried adding the .last method to the end of the snapshot. But

**"The argument type 'Future<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>?'.",**

Gives a fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firestore has no built in concept of a timestamp for each document of when it was created or updated **that you can use as a condition in a query**.

If you need this, you'll have to add a timestamp field to each document yourself. Once that exists, you can get the latest document with:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('users')
    .orderBy('yourTimestampField', descending: true)
    .limit(1)
    .snapshots(),
},
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [ordering and limiting data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data)

Comment: I edited my code. I have a model named User. How can I define TimeStamp inside it?

Comment: Please post your model